# Cannot connect Gear emulator with host device

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I have a problem in connecting my host device (Galaxy S3) with Gear emulator. I have followed [this tutorial](http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/Guideline_on_Testing_Gear_applications_using_the_Emulator.pdf) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=SFz3n49QUCs) from Samsung and it was working only one time, and never works again. I have tried to run "killall sap-server" as it suggests, but the result in Gear emulator's shell is "no process found". I have tried to restart my computer, and go through the steps again multiple times, but I still cannot connect my mobile device with the Gear emulator again.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide much more details, please attach corresponding parts of log at least and list steps you did before. It is good idea to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a gist of how SO works ;)

Answer (score 3):

***Note :***

As m.wasowski stated you need to give more details about your question

***Possible Solution 1 :***

Check your firewall, try to disable your protection application (Antivirus/Firewall) and try again.

***Possible Solution 2 :***

Updates your Samsung applications : http://developer.samsung.com/gear

***Possible Solution 3 :*** Try this steps :

On your computer :

```
taskkill -im adb.exe
adb -d forward tcp:8230 tcp:8230
```

On emulator's sdb shell :

```
killall sap-server
vconftool set -t int memory/wms/wmanager_connected 1 -f
```

***Alternative :***

You can test your apps remotely, follow the Samsung guide : [Test gear apps remotely](http://developer.samsung.com/what-is-new/blog/2014/Testing-apps-on-the-Gear2-Remotely;jsessionid=KVx9V5DLK1nGlPS76PNWy1mLFfhGpyyLG721pKrz7GgvkBTTpvj1!93449960)